# Xamarin IOS CoreML Model Change Multipler (posenet)

Tags: xamarin.ios, coreml, mobilenet, mlmodel

[image]I am using Xamarin IOS, I need to change the 'multipler' value of this **CoreML** MLModel as instructed here

***'A model with a 0.50 multiplier is recommended for mobile.'*
*https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet***

the model I'm currently using has a *0.75 multipler (too slow)*, I have been trying to convert and amend this property on the model however, the property doesn't exist in Xamarin IOS, the model simply has a GetPrediction method that's it!

For Javascript it seems you are able to set the properties as you wish, like below however all I need is Posenet as an .MLModel file with a multipler of 0.5.

//This code below isn't possible using Xamarin IOS, the only property the model has is a bool *'RunOnGPUAndCpu'* and a method *'GetPrediction'*

```
  const net = await posenet.load({
  architecture: 'MobileNetV1',
  outputStride: 16,
  inputResolution: { width: 640, height: 480 },
  multiplier: 0.75
  });
```

Ive attempted to convert a Tensorflow model with no luck!

Comment: I don't see this property listed in the Apple Docs for MLModel

Comment: I've added an image it shows were I got my model from on Apples Models page, they do a model for both 1.0 and 0.75 but there isn't one for 0.5, which directly contradicts 

'A model with a 0.50 multiplier is recommended for mobile.' https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet

Whom they reference on the same page!

Answer (score 0):

That multiplier isn't something you can apply to an existing model. Instead, it is used to define the architecture of the model, which is then trained. If you can't find a model with a 0.5 multiplier, you will have to train it yourself.